# Inductive types for large countable ordinal notations.

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, proof-theory

I'm looking to build notations for large countable ordinals in a "natural way".  By "natural way" I mean that given an inductive data type X, that equality should be the usual recursive equality (the same that `deriving Eq` in Haskell would produce) and the order should be the usual recursive lexicographical order (the same that `deriving Ord` in Haskell would produce), and there is a decidable predicate that determines if a member of X is a valid ordinal notation or not.

For example, ordinals less than ε<sub>0</sub> can be represented by hereditarily finite sorted lists and satisfies these requirements. Define X to be μα. μβ. 1 + α×β, a.k.a. hereditarily finite lists.  Define `isValid` to check that X is sorted and all members of X are `isValid`.  The valid members of X are all ordinals less than ε<sub>0</sub> under the usual lexicographical order.

I conjecture that μα<sub>0</sub>.… μα<sub>n</sub>. 1 + α<sub>0</sub>×…×α<sub>n</sub> can be used to define ordinals less than φ<sub>n + 1</sub>(0), where φ is the Veblen function, in a similar way.

As you can see I run out of μ quantifiers at φ<sub>ω</sub>(0). Can I build larger ordinal notations satisfying my requirements?  I was hoping to get as far as Γ<sub>0</sub>.  Can I get larger ordinals if I drop my decidability requirement on my validity predicate?

Comment: Have you seen Cantor in the Coq contribs? http://coq.inria.fr/pylons/pylons/contribs/view/Cantor/v8.3 It seems intuitive to me that Veblen normal form is "natural" in the way you specify. Is that not the case?

Comment: What does the theory say, how far can you go with having decidable equality? At some point you have to give up decidability and be satisfies with semidecidability.

Comment: The type that encodes the Veblen form has decidable ordering, but I'm not sure if validity is decidable. ordering is `compare` in http://coq.inria.fr/pylons/contribs/files/Cantor/v8.3/Cantor.gamma0.Gamma0.html In that same file, there is a Lemma `nf_intro` which might characterize validity.

Comment: @jbapple: this pretty much looks like the answer, perhaps you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @jbapple `Inductive lt : T2 -> T2 -> Prop` doesn't look like lexicographical ordering to me.

Comment: @Russell O'Connor: I agree with you, but I still think it is possible that Veblen notation had a natural `Ord`. I have two reasons: 1. lt is not restricted to well-formed (or `nf` in this Coq development) ordinals. Maybe `nf a -> nf b -> (lt a b <-> lexlt a b)`, for `lexlt` meaning lexicographic ordering. 2. The Wikipedia article on Veblen functions makes Veblen notation seem like Cantor normal form, which is lexicographic. Maybe this subquestion is more suited for mathoverflow.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer: Like Russell, I have some doubts. If it pans out, I'll summarize it in an answer.

Comment: Ok, why do you insist on getting Ord right automatically? You can always define an instance that suits your needs.

Comment: @Andrej No particular reason. It's just the type for ordinals less than &epsilon;<sub>0</sub> is so nice. I want to know how far we can go with that. Everything else feels like ad-hoc encodings.

Answer (score 4):

Hermann Ruge Jervel has a nice system that goes all the way to the Bachmann-Howard ordinal based on labelled trees.  See: http://folk.uio.no/herman/logsem.pdf

I also like his book on proof theory, which discusses this system: http://folk.uio.no/herman/bevisteori.ps

Comment: I don't think this is "natural" in the way specified in the question - see slides 7 and 8.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore